# Hitting enter to move a to next text field, like tab key?

Tags: java, actionlistener, jtextfield, enter

I am creating a simple form for a class and I want the user to be able to press <kbd>enter</kbd> after filling out one `JTextField`. It moves on to the next available `JTextField` *(not all of them are editable at a given time)*, similar to using <kbd>tab</kbd>.

When it gets to the last editable `JTextField` it should submit the form. Is that possible or is tab and the usual <kbd>enter</kbd> function *(as a submit my only option)*?

I'll post the code if necessary, but if you can answer the question without it, that'd be great too.

Comment: Yes its possible, there are multiple ways even to achieve it.

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing ? It would be unexpected for users as the standard is to use Enter for submitting the form and Tab for moving to next field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Durandal mentioned, there are multiple ways to go about it.

You could use JTextField's `addActionListener` method, `addAction` method, `addKeyListener` method, etc... They're all fairly similar - you're telling the text field to do something when something happens. (Although exactly how you do it differs by method)

Regardless, each time the action will need to know which text field is next in line. Then you can call `JTextField#requestFocus()` to transfer input focus to it.

You can also do this with `setFocusTraversalKeys` and `setNextFocusableComponent`

Comment: This statement salutation.setNextFocusableComponent(comments); is now showing up as deprecated. Do these methods still work in Java 8 and onward?